# What is the difference b/w a docker image generated by docker-compose build vs docker build?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

While building a docker image, image id is different if the image is built using `docker-compose build` vs `docker build`. The env has different hostname.

What else is different? Why images are different?

Comment: I believe there are no other differences other than container name, which `docker-compose` automatically generates, but you can specify when you use `docker-build`.

Comment: It's still an open issue: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/883

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no differences between the actual image that gets built between `docker-compose build` and a "manual" `docker build` in terms of the contents of the image.

The difference is only in naming/tagging of the build result, which `docker-compose` does automatically for you.
Other than that, the `docker-compose` build is no different behind the scenes and simply a wrapper for the normal `docker build`.

Comment: but i do see a difference between the generate images. As part  of my dockerfile i do a "npm install" to download all dependencies. 

The image built using "docker build" has all downloaded "npm_modules", whereas the one generated using "docker-compose up" has an empty "npm_modules" folder.

Comment: There must be something different in the way they work. In my project `docker build .` works, but `docker-compose build` gives out some error. The point is if one works, the other needn't work.

Comment: @GiriB would be good to know the error :) In all likelihood there's just something wrong with you `docker-compose.yml` in that case.

Comment: @ArminBraun I remember now, the `docker-compose` I was using was not compatible with the `docker-compose.yml` file. Sorry for the confusion! Updating `docker-compose` worked.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the naming difference, there could be difference in the resulting image if the parameters of the builds are different: the build: section of the docker-compose.yml and the command line parameters of the docker build command.
For example the --build-args can be different.